# Issue with memory usage using MahApps Metro in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm converting a winform project to a WPF project and using [MahApps Metro Window](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) for the themes. 
But when I tried to check the memory usage of it, it uses 32MB of memory. And when I tried to check the memory usage of the winform it only uses 5MB of memory. And I think that is a huge difference to think that the WPF project still unfinished while the winform is completely finished.

Please advise what will I do. Thanks guys. :)

Comment: WPF consumes more memory than winforms in smaller UIs. 
Still, 32 MB is completely negligible. If you really need to save memory, shut down the computer. The computer in power off state consumes 0 kb of memory, but the features available when the computer is on `just` might not be available when it is not.

Comment: When the application left running, it reaches 80MB, while winform just adds up 1MB. How about that?

Comment: how much RAM does the average John Smith's computer have? why do you care about that? the reason to switch from winforms to WPF is to actually be able to create an application that doesn't look like Windows 95, that WILL require more RAM. If you need to save memory, forget .Net and code stricly in Assembler or C++ and take care of moving individual bytes in memory from here to there.

Comment: Sorry Mr. Smith, in our company most computers uses 1-2GB of RAM, and in production the employees use lots of applications at the same time. That's why I'm concern about this.

Comment: then stick to winforms, WPF needs more RAM, because it actually has features.

Comment: I'm confused. Is the issue here WPF or MahApps? Have you tried a vanilla WPF app versus vanilla winforms app and compared memory usage then? Sounds like you're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @JRC i think this is not a problem with MahApps Metro. try creating a really simple wpf app and look to your code! with wpf you can make bad code to consume memory like with winforms. and, don't compare winforms with wpf, that's not the question!

Comment: @jomsk1e If your firm's pc's RAMs are that low, probably you shouldn't use WPF for your desktop apps. Btw, you need to compare a bare WPF program without MahApp.Metro in order to compare(maybe accuse?) the inefficiency of memory usage of the latter :)